# misunderstanding of scopes and variables

Tags: java, arrays, scope

About the following code fragment :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int temp;

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (int k = i + 1; k < arr.length; k++) {
            if (arr[i].getID() == arr[k].getID()) {
                temp = temp + arr[i].getDuration() + arr[k].getDuration();
            } else {

            }
        }

        if (temp!=0) {
            System.out.println(temp);
        }
        else {
            System.out.println(arr[i].getID());
        }

        temp=0;
    }
```

}

Where arr is constructed with an integer ID and another Integer Duration.
My goal is to iterate the loop in order to get all the possible permutations.
If IDs are the same, then add the duration of one to another.
temp allows me to sum the duration when the compared IDs are equal; although after the first run of the inner loop, which works fine, temp keeps his value of 0, even when the conditions to perform the sum are met.

Here's some hardcode of array arr:

```
    songs[] arr = new songs[4];  // array of object, seemed irrelevant for the problem at hand
    arr[0] = new songs(111,55);
    arr[1] = new songs(111, 58);
    arr[2] = new songs (222, 44);
    arr[3] = new songs (222, 88);
```

It seems like that at run-time, whence the variable temp is initiated to =0 for the first time, its value doesn't change anymore. Above, arr[2] and arr[3] have both same ID, but when temp is never printed; instead the ID at arr[i].getID is.

I assume the issue is due to the scope of variable temp. If anyone could push me in the good direction, that would help me out a lot !

Another side question : right now, my solution prints for each array of arr. ideally, i wish to print a line once per ID; is my approach able to satisfy this specification ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: too many empty lines in code, wrong indentation, does not make the code very readable

Comment: Where are you declaring `temp`?

Comment: The code does not even compile: it's missing a `;` and this line `System.out.println(arr[i].getID)` is missing both the parenthesis and the `;`.

Comment: apologize for the syntactic errors, didn't want to copy the entire code and ended up missing few stuff while editing

Comment: Your code doesn't compile because you do not initialize the local variable `temp`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't declare temp in the example.  There must be an "int temp" somewhere and It must be before the entire code block you posted in order to work the way you would like.

Also your test/print stuff should be after the last closing brace, otherwise you are checking it on each iteration of i

song.getID() should return an int for this to work, not an Integer (you said integer which is not a valid type).  If it's an Integer, then change your == to .equals() instead.

Either of these problems could have ended up with the results you saw (a temp of 0)

If you posted an entire working code sample it would be eaiser to be more sure what the problem was

Comment: "If it's an Integer, then change your == to .equals() instead." Nailed it, appreciate the help !

Answer (score -1):

You are declaring temp variable inside a for loop. There are different scopes in Java. Global, method and block/loop. Currently you are using a loop variable that cannot be used outside the loop, hence, you should pre-declare it as a method variable, that way you are able to use it outside the for loop.

Basically here, your temp inside the for-loop is different from the one outside, and both hold different values. Hence the outcome as 0.

As per your second question, I think one solution would be to print each arr[i].getID in the for loop itself with println(). Give it a shot and please let me know if this worked or not.

Comment: Actually he does not declare temp anyhere in the code he pasted here.

Comment: your explication helps out for novice like me, thanks for taking your time to help me out ! As for the second part, i assume i didn't make myself clear; I want to print similar IDs only once, not for each time my loop processes them.

Comment: @applz sorry, i didn't understood. Regarding the id then, you might want to iterate through the arrays comparing your ID's for the ones that repeat and store them in another array. Like " if they repeat store only 1 of this ID and the ones that don't repeat store them as well, as they are unique. Please let me know if this confuses you.